# How to integrate Google translate into a web-based chat application?

Tags: http, chat, translation, google-translate, messenger

I want to build a site and/or app that includes a messenger that automatically translates text between users (with option to turn off). I have no experience building sites or messengers and so I'm here asking if this is possible and looking for a jump-off point to get coding/researching (mainly with the translation integration. The rest I can find quite easily).

If it's possible, what would the general process of performing such an integration?

What languages/toolkits might I need?

I'd want the flow to work like: User A writes the message, it's sent to user B in user A's language, then translated by user B's machine and presented.

Answer (score 1):

Google translte has [api and documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started).

Also ure can see to [yandex translte api](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/). In lager scaile it is chipeer and in small scale it is free.
In [self project](https://github.com/CppComet/Star.Comet-Chat/blob/master/translateMessage.php) i was use yandex translate api.

This example of using yandex api. It is simple.

```
$translate = file_get_contents("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=".$yandex_translate_key."&text=".urlencode($messageText)."&lang=".$language."&options=1");
if(!$translate)
{
    die("Error");
}
$data = json_decode($translate, true);
var_dump($data)
```